# How do i set a cookie when a form submits from PHP?

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, setcookie, onsubmit

How do i set a cookie when a form submits?

this is the code im going to use once the cookies is there.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['v_regUsr']))
{
header("Location: dont-show-pop-up-with-form.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: show-pop-up-form.php");
}
?>
```

But i need a cookie to be set with the name or value of 'v_regUsr' when a form is submitted.

So the user goes to the site. the page checks to see if the cookie is there...If it is then it wont show a pop up. If the cookie isnt there then it should show a popup with the "form"

Once the hit submit on the form the cookie "v_regUsr" is placed and they wont see the pop up again.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://app.buildtopia.com/english/include/jquery-plugins/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://app.buildtopia.com/english/include/jquery-plugins/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theForm").validate();
  });
</script>




<style type="text/css">
  #theForm { width: 100%; }
  #theForm label { display: block; float: left; width: 200px; text-align: right; padding-right: 5px; margin-right: 10px; }
  #theForm label.required { border-right: solid 3px red; }
  #theForm fieldset { border: none; margin: 0 0 0 215px; }
  #theForm fieldset input { display: block; float: left; }
  #theForm fieldset label { float: none; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px; width: auto; }
  #theForm label.error, #theForm input.submit {  display: none; float: none; color: red; }
  .question { padding-bottom: 15px; }
</style>

 <form id="theForm" name="theForm" action="send.php" method="post"> 
      <div class="question">
 <label for="fname"  class="required"  >First Name</label>
 <input id="fname" name="fname" size="25" maxlength="40"  validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter your first name'}}"  /> 
 </div>
<div class="question">
 <label for="lname"  class="required"  >Last Name</label>
 <input id="lname" name="lname" size="25" maxlength="40"  validate="{required:true, messages:{required:'Please enter your last name'}}"  /> 
 </div>
<div class="question">
 <label for="home_phone"  class="required"  >Home Phone</label>
 <input id="home_phone" name="home_phone" size="15" maxlength="20"  validate="{required:true}"  /> 
 </div>
<div class="question">
 <label for="email1"  class="required"  >Email (Primary)</label>
 <input id="email1" name="email1" size="50" maxlength="55" validate="{ required:true,  email:true }" /> 
 </div>
<div align="right">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://in3.php.net/setcookie

Comment: But i need the code for when the user hits submit to set a cookie

Comment: shouldnt it be like onSubmit "form" setcookie("v_regUsr", "value");

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("v_regUsr", "value");
```

You can also add a valid duration to your cookie:

```
setcookie("v_regUsr", "value", time()+3600*24*365);  // 1 year.
```

Comment: i know how to set the cookies.... i just need to know how to do it when the form submits only

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
 document.cookie="v_regUsr=" + cookievalue;
```

Ref: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

If you want to set cookie using php, use **[setcookie()](https://www.php.net/setcookie)** function

```
$value = 'Your Values';
setcookie("v_regUsr", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
```

**Update:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {      
   $("#theForm").validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {
       // do other things for a valid form
             var cookievalue="your value";
             document.cookie="v_regUsr=" + cookievalue;
             form.submit();
          }
      });
});
```

Comment: i know how to set the cookies.... i just need to know how to do it when the form submits only

Comment: that is what im lacking, all i have is a working form...im missing the   javascript @Krish R

Comment: form onsubmit call jaavscript function, inside that function set teh cookie. Show your html, so that i can help you more

Comment: it looks like it will work but it does not place the cookie...am i missing something? @Krish R

Comment: how you checked the cookie values ?

Comment: i checked to see if the cookie was placed through chrome

Comment: you didnt find the value of cookie? or even cookie name

Comment: no i didnt find any cookie, it should be in the root folder right? atleast on that domain

Comment: `var allcookies = document.cookie; alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );` add this lines after setcookie to know

Comment: that worked but i didnt see the new cookie in there after i submi

Comment: You can set cookie either ways php or javascript, i have given two ways. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm

Comment: i just dont understand why its not working... something must be missing in my code

Comment: why can't you check this piece of line in other file `var allcookies = document.cookie; alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );` to verify the cookie values?

Comment: i did use that to check and the cookie is not there

Comment: can you check into firefox `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48516/discussion-between-user2405912-and-krish-r)